# How to update items from datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I want to update invoice and invoice has multiple items i retrieve invoice items from Database to `DataGridView` now user can remove the items and can add the items and user will click on update button to update the invoice in database.

My Code:

```
try
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(AppSettings.ConnectionString()))
            {
                con.Open();
                for (int j = 0; j < dgv.Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    using (SQLiteCommand sc = new SQLiteCommand("Update Orders Set [Order_No] = @Order_No,[Order_Type] = @Order_Type,[Order_Date] = @Order_Date,[Customer_Name] = @Customer_Name,[Contact] = @Contact,[Adress] = @Adress,[Delivery_Address] = @Delivery_Address,[Rider] = @Rider,[Items] = @Items,[Price] = @Price,[Qty] = @Qty,[Item_Total] = @Item_Total,[Item_Cat] = @Item_Cat,[SubTotal] = @SubTotal,[Discount] = @Discount,[Total_Amount] = @Total_Amount,[Paid_Amount] = @Paid_Amount,[Change_Due] = @Change_Due,[Delivery_Charges] = @Delivery_Charges Where Order_No = '" + Order_No.Text + "' ", con))
                    {
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Order_No", Order_No.Text);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Order_Type", Order_Type.Text);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Order_Date", Order_Date.Text);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer_Name", Customer_Name.Text);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", Contact.Text);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Adress", Address.Text);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Delivery_Address", Delivery_Address.Text);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rider", "");
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Items", dgv.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", dgv.Rows[j].Cells[2].Value);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", dgv.Rows[j].Cells[3].Value);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item_Total", dgv.Rows[j].Cells[4].Value);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item_Cat", dgv.Rows[j].Cells[5].Value);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubTotal", SubTotal.Text);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Discount", Discount.Text);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_Amount", Total_Amount.Text);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Paid_Amount", Paid_Amount.Text);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Change_Due", Change_Due.Text);
                        sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Delivery_Charges", Del_Charges.Text);
                        sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }

                SuccessBox sb = new SuccessBox();
                sb.lbl_Change.Text = Change_Due.Text;
                sb.label1.Text = "Successfully Updated";
                sb.ShowDialog();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

if i add new item and click on update button so this query replaces my all old items with new one.

Suppose i add Samsung S8 so it willl replace my old items to Samsung S8.

And the result is:

```
Samsung S8   1   $750
Samsung S8   1   $750
Samsung S8   1   $750
Samsung S8   1   $750
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: so you want updated value in gridview right?

Comment: You didn't set `@OrderID` parameter

Comment: I keep seeing more and more reasons this won't even compile. Please update the question with the code that is really running.

Comment: The best way is to use a DataAdapter to fill a DataTable and the use the DGV dataSource as the DataTable.  The reason is the DataTable has an AcceptChanges() method which automatically updates the database.  For this to work you also need to use a Commandbuilder.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples

Comment: kindly check my code and suggest me what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Set The OrderID Parameter in order to Update the desired Item

Answer (score 0):

This will do the Insert, Update, and Delete for you, all via a DataGrid object.

```
using System;  
using System.Data;  
using System.Windows.Forms;  
using System.Data.SqlClient;  

namespace InsertUpdateDeleteDemo  
{  
    public partial class frmMain : Form  
    {  
        SqlConnection con= new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Sample;Integrated Security=true;");  
        SqlCommand cmd;  
        SqlDataAdapter adapt;  
        //ID variable used in Updating and Deleting Record  
        int ID = 0;  
        public frmMain()  
        {  
            InitializeComponent();  
            DisplayData();  
        }  
        //Insert Data  
        private void btn_Insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  
            if (txt_Name.Text != "" && txt_State.Text != "")  
            {  
                cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_Record(Name,State) values(@name,@state)", con);  
                con.Open();  
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txt_Name.Text);  
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", txt_State.Text);  
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
                con.Close();  
                MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted Successfully");  
                DisplayData();  
                ClearData();  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                MessageBox.Show("Please Provide Details!");  
            }  
        }  
        //Display Data in DataGridView  
        private void DisplayData()  
        {  
            con.Open();  
            DataTable dt=new DataTable();  
            adapt=new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbl_Record",con);  
            adapt.Fill(dt);  
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;  
            con.Close();  
        }  
        //Clear Data  
        private void ClearData()  
        {  
            txt_Name.Text = "";  
            txt_State.Text = "";  
            ID = 0;  
        }  
        //dataGridView1 RowHeaderMouseClick Event  
        private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)  
        {  
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());  
            txt_Name.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();  
            txt_State.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();  
        }  
        //Update Record  
        private void btn_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  
            if (txt_Name.Text != "" && txt_State.Text != "")  
            {  
                cmd = new SqlCommand("update tbl_Record set Name=@name,State=@state where ID=@id", con);  
                con.Open();  
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);  
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txt_Name.Text);  
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", txt_State.Text);  
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
                MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");  
                con.Close();  
                DisplayData();  
                ClearData();  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select Record to Update");  
            }  
        }  
        //Delete Record  
        private void btn_Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  
            if(ID!=0)  
            {  
                cmd = new SqlCommand("delete tbl_Record where ID=@id",con);  
                con.Open();  
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",ID);  
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
                con.Close();  
                MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted Successfully!");  
                DisplayData();  
                ClearData();  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select Record to Delete");  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: I can also update the data with textboxes but i want to update the gridview items